# Question about the implementation of page_address()

Tags: linux-kernel

On x86 machines with highmem, when the kernel wants to query the kernel virtual address of a physical frame, it will use `page_address`. How it works depends on whether the macro WANT_PAGE_VIRTUAL is defined, which decides if `void *virtual` is added in `struct page`. If there is no `void *virtual`, the kernel will use a hash table `page_address_htable` to do the conversion, and this seems the method x86 applies. On the contrary, mips and m68k just take `void *virtual`(I'm not very sure for this).

So my question is, why x86 prefers a hash table to a improved `struct page`? What are the benefits it brings about?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since there are a lot of `struct page` needed (one for every page!) it is very expensive to add even one more word to the structure (or conversely, shrinking the struct by even one word gives a lot of benefit).  On 32-bit architectures `WANT_PAGE_VIRTUAL` is especially expensive -- without it, struct page is exactly 32 bytes, which means it packs nicely into cachelines etc.

On x86 the hash lookup is fast enough (since multiplication is fast on x86) that the tradeoff is strongly in favor of making struct page smaller.  I guess on m68k multiplication is expensive enough that bloating struct page to 36 bytes is worth it.